# Migrate multiple custom fields to just one Fluid Field

Tags: channel-entries, fluid-field

Grown with the years, one of my projects consists of *several* Channels with *several* Field Groups and dozens of custom fields. Now with ExpressionEngine 4 and the new fluid field we want to consolidate most of the custom fields so we're not longer depending on so many custom fields … whats the easiest and safest way to migrate from «multiple custom fields to one fluid field»?

For example – right now we have Channel1, Channel2, Channel3 etc. each with field groups with custom fields like channel1-bodytext, channel2-bodytext, channel3-bodytext and of course many, many more.

How can I migrate/export/import those into just one text-field inside one fluid field used by all channels?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any add-on that will do this kind of transformation, but if you are comfortable working on your EE4 database directly using SQL it is certainly possible to do that way.

I had to do this recently sorting out an EE2 site being migrated to EE4.  For that work I was pulling entries from channels and writing them to fluid fields (including grid fields).  Worked OK.  Didn't try and migrate relationship fields - but imagine that they are doable too.

A detailed description of what to do is beyond scope of this kind of space, but simplistically:

- Use EE to create the fluid fields you need
- Put one unique fake entry information in each field
- Use something like Sequel Pro to find the definition information for each field created (e.g. the channel field / grid number, and the position of the field in the fluid field register)
- For each field, generate a list of the entry_id's of the entries that you want to migrate and that have a value in the field
- Construct a custom SQL query to copy the content of the migrating fields to the new fluid field entry - you will need to make sure you increment some counters in the fluid field register to do this correctly
- (side note - I wrote a set of EE templates to automatically generate the required SQL queries - saved a lot of time)
- test / delete the old fields.

This is a non-trivial activity for you by sound of it, but once you get hang of how it works it should be manageable.

Usual words of caution - back everything up, and do this work on a development server... it is easy to break things.

Of course if you want someone else to do it for you... drop me a line via my website :)